# Even though I have a scoped nested route, my resources are not routing properly - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my route:

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

So when I go to `mydomain.com/test/feedbacks/10` it shows the correct `feedback` with `id=10` that belongs to `username=test`.

But, if I go to `mydomain.com/test2/feedbacks/10` it shows me the same feedback with `id=10`, which does NOT belong to `username=test2`.

How do I restrict this from happening?

I am using the `Vanity` gem to give me the username in the URL, this is what that route looks like:

```
controller :vanities do 
    match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\+\@]+/}
  end
```

**Edit 1:**

That is to say, for clarity's sake, when I go to `mydomain.com/test/feedbacks/10` and `/test2/feedbacks/10`, it shows me the same view for the same record (in which case, the latter version would be wrong because it should be telling me that no such record exists, but it's not. It is just displaying the correct record for `test/feedbacks/10`).

**Edit 2:**

Here are the logs of both requests:

*The right request*

```
Started GET "/test-3/feedbacks/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-14 02:48:15 -0500
  Processing by FeedbacksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"test-3", "id"=>"7"}
  Feedback Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Rendered feedbacks/show.html.erb within layouts/application (36.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 188ms (Views: 184.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

*The wrong request*

```
Started GET "/test2/feedbacks/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-14 02:48:28 -0500
  Processing by FeedbacksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"test2", "id"=>"7"}
  Feedback Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Rendered feedbacks/show.html.erb within layouts/application (37.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 47.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: Are you checking if the record is owned by the user? This doesn't get done automatically.

Comment: Do post your #show action code, you should be looking into params[:username] and loading your user record accordingly.  Also do what @Benoit said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your show action should look something like

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

  if @user == current_user
    ...
    render "show"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Record doesn't exist"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I took the liberty of adding in @Benoit's suggestion.

Comment: Hrmm...I haven't added any user authorization gem yet (like declarative_authorization). Is that why this doesn't restrict it?

Comment: What about authentication? (Devise, auth from scratch etc.)  This alone wouldn't restrict it; it does however allow you to check if the current logged in user is the same as the record found.  Devise sets up the `current_user` method.

Comment: I haven't added authentication yet. Just building out the barebones functionality of the app first. Will add Devise after I am finished with this section though. If Devise will solve that problem, then I am fine. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't a routing issue that I missed when I am setting up my custom routing.

Comment: Is that the case, by the way? That once I install Devise, it will enforce those things, and it's not a routing issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a routing issue, your 'routes' dont' have any logic to determine what information to return from your models - you set this logic up in your controllers.  I'd imagine you'd only consider adding authorization (yes, decl_auth or Cancan for example) in conjunction with authentication - not without.

Comment: If you don't setup Devise, you won't be able to test logic that checks if the current user is the logged in user =) "Just building out the barebones functionality of the app first" - I'm not sure about others, but I tend to finish all the authentication stuff first; your way feels rather 'cart before the horse'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3438/discussion-between-mike-and-marcamillion)